# How to create a new UIWindowScene from drag'n'drop?

Tags: ios, ipad, drag-and-drop, ios13, multi-window

I'm trying to implement the new multi-window in iPadOS, and I struggle with drag'n'drop.

In this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/212/) they show us an example where a new scene is created after draging a mail to the side of the screen (at 11:45).

How can we do that? In the few other videos on the subject, they always create a new scene by tapping a button and calling appdelegate's `requestSceneSessionActivation`.

Does anybody knows how to create a new scene like in the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the [WWDC 2019 Session 212 page](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/212/), there is a link to the [Supporting Multiple Windows on iPad](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/supporting_multiple_windows_on_ipad) sample app that goes with the video. This is the Gallery app they demonstrate including the code to create a new scene via drag and drop.

The basic idea is to create an `NSUserActivity` representing enough data to create the new scene.

In the appropriate drag delegate method (such as `tableView(_:itemsForBeginning:at:)` or `collectionView(_:itemsForBeginning:at:)`), you create a `UIDragItem` from the `NSUserActivity`.

That lets you create the drag item which you drag off to the side of the screen. The other half of the process is to handle the provided `NSUserActivity` in your `UIWindowSceneDelegate`. You use the data in the `NSUserActivity` to setup the newly created scene.

Comment: Thanks! Shame on me for not checking the sample of the video is was referring to.